# Data from database not showing in view after user logs in [codeigniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, authentication

After the user logs in (using codeigniter), it displays a private area which is supposed to show news articles stored in the database- and it shows nothing. I have tried and tested the url link to this and displays fine- only after the user logs in. Any help would be appreciated.

NEWS MODEL:

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getArticle () {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('news');
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```

}

NEWS CONTROLLER:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/news_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array('news' => $this->news_model->getArticle());
        $data['title'] = 'Admin | News Home';
        $data['heading'] = 'News Articles';
        $this->load->view('admin/news', $data); 
}
```

}

NEWS VIEW:

```
   <?php foreach ($news as $article): ?>
        <h2><?php echo $article['title'] ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $article['content'] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $article['author'] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $article['date'] ?></p>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

I have tried passing the data though an object as well as an array and still no luck. I havent posted the login model/view/controller incase the problem is in here but can if this looks correct.

Any guidance will help as ive just fixed one bug and this has happened! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to troubleshoot your problem:

```
public function index() {
     $data = array('news' => $this->news_model->getArticle());
     $data['title'] = 'Admin | News Home';
     $data['heading'] = 'News Articles';

     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($data);
     echo "</pre>";

     $this->load->view('admin/news', $data); 
}
```

The code above should give you the structure of the `$data` variable. If your news articles are not showing, you should backtrack your steps until you find the source of your problem.

Comment: Tried this and still a no go- thanks though for the help, realised as well instead of directing to http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/admin/news its using the method and directing to http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/login/login_validation, may have to look at my controller in the registration!

Comment: @Balboa let us know when you make any new discovery, would be interesting to know why your code isn't working.